# Cannot find numpy module

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am trying to run a python file which needs numpy as an import.

I have set up an environment where numpy is installed via Anaconda. I am also using pypy, and when I try to run the file using

```
pypy myFile.py
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I then run pip list to check the packages currently installed in the enivornment and numpy is there

```
certifi      2018.11.29
mkl-fft      1.0.10
mkl-random   1.0.2
numpy        1.15.4
pip          19.0.1
setuptools   40.8.0
wheel        0.32.3
wincertstore 0.2
```

I'm not sure why it is not finding numpy, any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use `python myFile.py` and not `pypy`?

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056963/how-to-install-pypy-in-anaconda

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters No, I don't get the error if I use python instead of pypy

Answer (score 0):

If you used conda to install Numpy, you probably installed a version that is not compatible with pypy. Use pip instead. Jump into your virtual environment and:

```
conda uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Has to be something with my pypy as python myFile.py works fine

Comment: I've heard that numpy is "99% compatible with pypy". You can trying installing numpypy as well.