# Conda create virtual environtment with pypy as interpreter in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, conda, pypy

I have successfully installed conda and pypy because of this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056963/how-to-install-pypy-in-anaconda), I'm using VSCode as text editor. Yes I can use pypy but it seems installed for global environtment instead of virtual environtment. I want use pypy in virtual environtment with conda so the package will insttalled locally instead of globally.

The tutor I saw in previous stackoverflow will created virtual environtment with common python interpreter instead of pypy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a conda environment first:

```
conda create -n pypy3 -c conda-forge pypy3.5
```

Afterwards you have to link to the pypy3 interpreter within the bin directory of the env:

```
ln -s pypy3 python
```